# Add days to a date without timezone

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, discord.js

The `Now()` function displays the date.

The `addDays()` function allows you to add days to the date.

The problem is that the date display the timezone:
`2021-01-07T08: 00: 33.000Z`

**I want**: `2021-01-07 08:00:00`

Anyone have any help please?

```js
function NOW() {

   var date = new Date();
   var aaaa = date.getFullYear();
   var gg = date.getDate();
   var mm = (date.getMonth() + 1);

   if (gg < 10)
       gg = "0" + gg;

   if (mm < 10)
       mm = "0" + mm;

   var cur_day = aaaa + "-" + mm + "-" + gg;

   var hours = date.getHours()
   var minutes = date.getMinutes()
   var seconds = date.getSeconds();

   if (hours < 10)
       hours = "0" + hours;

   if (minutes < 10)
       minutes = "0" + minutes;

   if (seconds < 10)
       seconds = "0" + seconds;

   return cur_day + " " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

}
function addDays(date, days) {
   var result = new Date(date);
   result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
   return result;
 }
```

Comment: Your solution seems to work fine - is there a problem you're trying to fix?

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to return the result `toLocaleString` in your `addDays` function.

```js
return result.toLocaleString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mostly there.  Just change NOW() to take an argument that you need to format and print.  Basically you'll remove the `var date = new Date();` and use the passed in argument.

```
function formatDate(date) {
  var aaaa = date.getFullYear();
  ..
  ..
}
```

And then you can pass in the result of addDays() to this function

```
formatDate(addDays(new Date(), 1))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks you for your help but it is not resolving. I think you don't understand my problem. I want to add days at today's date like : (2020-01-02) + 10 days  = (2020-01-12)

Comment: @RjjfjfkFkkfkf currently it is 2021 ^^

Comment: Something like this? 
var d = new Date(); d.setDate(d.getDate() + 10); console.log(d.getFullYear() + ":" + (d.getMonth() < 9 ? "0" : "") + (d.getMonth() + 1) + ":" + (d.getDate() < 10 ? "0" : "") + d.getDate())